# accesing Authenticated URl of image in Android

Tags: android, url, authentication, bitmapimage

I need to load, and update image from URL and the url is authenticated by .htaccess

Does any one know how to get access to this image file

My question is:-
how to set Credentials (in HttpUrlConnection ) when accessing such file

Comment: "authenticated by .htaccess" This doesn't sound like an Android-specific problem, unless you need to know how to detect a 403-denied HTTP error.

Comment: I assume he means HTTP basic authentication.

Comment: @Emyr : do you know how to set Credentials (in HttpUrlConnection ) when accessing such file

Comment: GIYF: http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-add-basic-authentication-into-httpurlconnection/140

Comment: In htaccess for making request i have used `DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user_name, password));`

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bmImg;
public Bitmap downloadFile(String stringURL)
{
    try 
    {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(myHtaccessUsername, myHTaccessPassword)); 
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(stringURL);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmImg;
}
```

This is the code that I used to solve this issue. I was using an HttpUrlConnection to pull photos from any public URL but when it came to a specific server that required a basic level of access (htaccess credentials) I could not use the HttpUrlConnection I assume because of the way a HttpUrlConnection handles the handshake or something. Using the DefaultHttpClient along with HttpGet, HttpResponse, and HttpEntity objects I was able to pull the photo resource with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

If it's basic authentication, just use an authenticator (Note, this is only for a GET request)

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication("myuser","mypass".toCharArray());
}});
```

then make your HttpURLConnection below that.

Comment: thanks for help.I have try this but the image is not displaying , I also check logcat it don't show any error

Comment: What is your code for 1. displaying the image, and 2. for making the connection? At this point it's unclear whether it's just not displaying the image correctly or if there's a problem making the connection.

Comment: I have use your code (as you have posted above) for authentication after this line I have write this : `Bitmap bmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(img_url).getContent()); imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);`